# Go: freegeoip deploying on heroku

Tags: heroku, go, dependency-management

while deploying on Heroku [freegeoip](https://github.com/fiorix/freegeoip) app I get errors. Before deploy I did `godep save` and it install some dependancies to `_workspace` directory of the project

```
Counting objects: 1210, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (690/690), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1210/1210), 631.22 KiB, done.
Total 1210 (delta 472), reused 1022 (delta 467)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote: -----> Go app detected
remote: -----> Installing go1.4... done
remote: -----> Running: godep go install -tags heroku ./...
remote: cmd/freegeoip/main.go:20:2: cannot find package "github.com/fiorix/go-redis/redis" in any of:
remote:     /app/tmp/cache/go1.4/go/src/github.com/fiorix/go-redis/redis (from $GOROOT)
remote:     /tmp/build_302ca8290b15fc58739db8af3cc335ac/.heroku/g/src/github.com/fiorix/freegeoip/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/fiorix/go-redis/redis (from $GOPATH)
remote:     /tmp/build_302ca8290b15fc58739db8af3cc335ac/.heroku/g/src/github.com/fiorix/go-redis/redis
remote: cmd/freegeoip/main.go:21:2: cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/context" in any of:
remote:     /app/tmp/cache/go1.4/go/src/github.com/gorilla/context (from $GOROOT)
remote:     /tmp/build_302ca8290b15fc58739db8af3cc335ac/.heroku/g/src/github.com/fiorix/freegeoip/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/gorilla/context (from $GOPATH)
remote:     /tmp/build_302ca8290b15fc58739db8af3cc335ac/.heroku/g/src/github.com/gorilla/context
remote: godep: go exit status 1
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Go app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to cryptic-temple-9401.
remote:
```

What should I do to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Are you following any tutorial to do this ? Using heroku-buildpack-go ? Scroll to the end of this page : https://mmcgrana.github.io/2012/09/getting-started-with-go-on-heroku.html

Comment: @Omie yes, I've create heroku app with `heroku-buildpack-go`

Comment: will need more details. what is your directory structure like ? could you provide output of `tree` ? what is in .godir ? might get some idea about setting the same from this gist and comments : https://gist.github.com/kr/299535bbf56bf3016cba